# How can I use a Unity C# script simultaneously in a non-Unity Linux program?

Tags: c#, unity, linux, macos

I have a C# script inside a Unity project. I'd to both keep using the script in this Unity project, *and* to use it to compile a non-Unity Linux daemon.

So I would basically need to create a new `Main` for this Linux daemon, and include this script, without using any of Unity's classes. Compiling it using Unity anyway is currently not an option.

However I'm a bit confused on how to do such a thing. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: @Byte56 I've searched on google and I've found many confusing infos, usually looking to do something different (such as running .NET, compiling different systems, running .asp, etc.).

Comment: First off, unity is not .NET, it's Mono, which will run just fine on Linux or OSX.
Second off, C# isn't a scripting language. 
Third off, running and compiling are not the same thing.
Is that thing you intend to run as a daemon the server logic of a game?

Comment: So why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: I'm guessing for the lack of trying anything. Just searching around isn't much of an attempt I think. Or the reasons in Timothy's comment.

Comment: Using a Unity script is a bit of a red flag for me since most of the scripting functions use Unity specific objects (like GameObject). If a script is devoid of all these dependencies you could easily add the script to it's own C# project and compile it to a dll as Tim says below. You then can import the dll to any program (unity or otherwise) that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile a .DLL from any mono project, and use that in Unity.

Move the portions of the code you want to keep outside the unity project to a new solution, and compile a DLL from them.

You can then import that DLL and use it in your Unity project.

Unity themselves provide examples of how to do this here :

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UsingDLL.html

The "daemon" you want to run can be created in a side project, and compiled separately.

Comment: This put me in the right track, but I don't really need to compile a DLL for that, just using the same source file in a common directory would be enough. Now I've created a new solution for the server and I'll try to do that, I'll come back and edit when I'm done.